# WordPress add_filter is not working for robots_txt in localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

I am a newbie in WordPress plugin development and i have kind of hit a roadblock in this matter. The thing is that using the filter `add_filter('robots_txt', 'AddToRobotsTxt', 10, 2);` does not create a **robots.txt**  file in my localhost i do not know what is the issue. I have set directory permissions to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Since I thought this might be causing the issue, I'm attaching the rest of my code.

```
public function allRobotSettings(){


    register_setting('energizer_robot_group', 'energizer_robots-name');

    add_settings_section('energizer_robot_index', 'Robot Setting', array( $this->callbacks_mngr, 'robotSectionManager' )
    , 'energizer_robots');

    add_settings_field('robot_field_manager', 'Robot Document', array( $this->callbacks_mngr, 'robotInputboxField' ),
    'energizer_robots', 'energizer_robot_index');
}
```

This function is for settings on html page.
And it calls these functions.

```
public function robotSectionManager()
{
    echo 'Edit your robot.txt file here.';
}

public function robotInputboxField()
{
    $data=get_option('energizer_robots-name');  

    add_filter( 'robots_txt', 'AddToRobotsTxt',10,2);
    $content=get_option('energizer_robots-name');   

    echo '<div ><input type="text"  name="energizer_robots-name" value="'. $content.'" 
    style="height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8; ></div>';
}
public function AddToRobotsTxt($robotstext, $public) {
    $robotsrules = get_option('energizer_robots-name');
    $new_value=$robotstext . $robotsrules;
    update_option( 'energizer_robots-name', $new_value);

    return $robotstext . $robotsrules;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just try adding this in your plugin base file, it can be moved to class on init action. Also please create one robots.txt file if there is not.

```
add_filter( 'robots_txt', 'AddToRobotsTxt',10,2);

function AddToRobotsTxt($robotstext, $public) {

    $robotsrules = get_option('energizer_robots-name');
    $new_value=$robotstext . $robotsrules;
    update_option( 'energizer_robots-name', $new_value);

    return $robotstext . $robotsrules;
}
```

Comment: Doesn,t this filter dynamically generate the robots.txt file if it is not present?

Comment: No, it will not generate a file if not present. It's filter for "do_robots" function output

Comment: Actually it is not working I have tried it make a robots.txt file in the activated theme then testing on it as well.